# guardar imagen pdf

Tags: c#, pdf

Buenas tardes.

Tengo un  tema al tratar de guardar un documento pdf en una carpeta local.

Con openFileDialog no me lo permite y con itextsharp no entiendo como hacer.

Yo lo que necesito es desde mi windows form, se abra un dialogo pueda seleccionar un documento pdf de la pc y guardarlo en una carpeta local. Y el path en la base de datos, para posteriormente llamarlo desde una aplicacion web.

de esta forma  no se  puede:

```
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        open.Filter = "Imagen Files (*.pdf)| *.pdf|ALL Files(*.*)|*.*";
        open.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (open.CheckFileExists)
            {
                string ruta = @"C:\Users\matias\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProyectoFinal\ProyectoFinal\Imagenes\PdfVentas\";
                string nombre = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(open.FileName);

                System.IO.File.Copy(nombre, ruta);

            }

        }
```

Y con itext no me doy cuenta como hacer, por que me crea un documento, no lo puedo seleccionar:

```
     Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
     PdfWriter writer = 
             PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\prueba.pdf",
             FileMode.Create));
     doc.open();
```

Si alguien me podria dar una mano le agradeceria.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo porque dices que no se puede con `File.Copy`. Si lo unico que quieres es copiar el pdf de una ruta a otra,utilizar iTextSharp no es necesario ni mucho menos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en el copy no le dices como tiene que llamarse el archivo.
La ruta de destino tiene que incluir el nombre.pdf

Prueba asi:

```
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
    open.Filter = "Imagen Files (*.pdf)| *.pdf|ALL Files(*.*)|*.*";
    open.FilterIndex = 1;

    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (open.CheckFileExists)
        {
            string ruta = @"C:\Users\matias\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ProyectoFinal\ProyectoFinal\Imagenes\PdfVentas\";

            System.IO.File.Copy(open.FileName, ruta + open.SafeFileName);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te ha funcionado dame un voto y marcalo como respuesta, por favor ^_^